# Why is the overriden val in constructor null?

Tags: scala, nullpointerexception, overriding

In the following scenario

```
class A(name:String, job:String) 
{ 
   def profile = name + " " + job 
}

class B(name:String, job:String) 
{ 
  val a = new A(name,job)
  val b = a.profile
}
```

On initializing `B` and overriding `val a`

```
val b = new B("Sasha","Day dream") 
{ override val a = new A("John-Wick","Kill") }
```

I get a `NullPointerException` for `val b = a.profile`. My question is why is the overriden `val` null ? Is doing something like above, a bad practice ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a combination of several facts:

1. `a` in `val b = a.profile` refers to the getter method, and it's the getter (and setter, for `var`) which gets overridden by `override val a`. So it returns the value of the field from the subclass.
2. The subclass field is initialized in the subclass constructor.
3. The `B` constructor runs *before* the subclass constructor, while the subclass field has its default value `null`.

A common fix is to switch `val`s to `lazy val`, so they are initialized on first use.

Comment: Could you elaborate more, how is it different from just calling val b = new B("Sasha","Day dream")

Comment: `new B("Sasha", "Day dream") { ... }` creates an anonymous class, it's the same as `class C() extends B("Sasha", "Day dream") { ... }; val b = new C()`.